# Message publishing to Google pub/sub with large delay

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, publish-subscribe

I'm newbie to Google pub/sub.
I'm using SpringBoot with starter `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub` to publish message to Google pub/sub. But sometimes my messages are publishing with large delay(~ 2 hours).
I'm using default configuration of client library.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/spring) help you?

Comment: What should I look into this? Application is already up and running in my case with proper logging setup.